# check for missing resolvers

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server, graphql-tools

How would you scan schema for missing resolver for queries and non-scalar fields ?

I'm trying to work with a dynamic schema so I need to be able to test this programmatically. I've been browsing graphql tools for few hours to find a way to do this, but I'm getting nowhere...

- [checkForResolveTypeResolver](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/blob/master/src/generate/checkForResolveTypeResolver.ts) - this only apply to interface and union resolveType resolver
- I can't find a way to know when a defaultFieldResolver is applied
- I tried working with custom directives to add @requiredResolver, to help identify those fields, but custom resolver are far from being fully supported:

  - [introspection & directives](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/300)
  - [no graphql-js directives handler](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1854) (can workaround this with graphql-tools tho)

any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an instance of GraphQLSchema (i.e. what's returned by `makeExecutableSchema`) and your `resolvers` object, you can just check it yourself. Something like this should work:

```
const { isObjectType, isWrappingType, isLeafType } = require('graphql')

assertAllResolversDefined (schema, resolvers) {
  // Loop through all the types in the schema
  const typeMap = schema.getTypeMap()
  for (const typeName in typeMap) {
    const type = schema.getType(typeName)
    // We only care about ObjectTypes
    // Note: this will include Query, Mutation and Subscription
    if (isObjectType(type) && !typeName.startsWith('__')) {
      // Now loop through all the fields in the object
      const fieldMap = type.getFields()
      for (const fieldName in fieldMap) {
        const field = fieldMap[fieldName]
        let fieldType = field.type

        // "Unwrap" the type in case it's a list or non-null
        while (isWrappingType(fieldType)) {
          fieldType = fieldType.ofType
        }

        // Only check fields that don't return scalars or enums
        // If you want to check *only* non-scalars, use isScalarType
        if (!isLeafType(fieldType)) {
          if (!resolvers[typeName]) {
            throw new Error(
              `Type ${typeName} in schema but not in resolvers map.`
            )
          }
          if (!resolvers[typeName][fieldName]) {
            throw new Error(
              `Field ${fieldName} of type ${typeName} in schema but not in resolvers map.`
            )
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I fixed missing logic, but apart from that, it works great ! I didn't know about these fancy methods (isObjectType, isWrappingType, isLeafType). Documentation isn't so great... Thanks !